# Conversion data type in spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an problem in my Spring MVC.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/novo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView novoTimeSheet() {
    return new ModelAndView("timesheetcrud/novo", "timesheet", new TimeSheet());
}
```

My `TimeSheet` class has:

```
@NotNull(message = "timesheet.cadastro.horainicio.obrigatorio")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "INICIO", nullable = false)
private Date horaInicio;

@NotNull(message = "timesheet.cadastro.horafim.obrigatorio")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@Column(name = "FIM", nullable = false)
private Date horaFim;
```

My `addTimeSheet`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addtimesheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTimeSheet(@ModelAttribute("timesheet")TimeSheet timeSheet,
                         ModelMap model) {
```

In browser when I put something not equal date, I have this error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors
Field error in object 'timesheet' on field 'horaFim': rejected value [lala]; 
codes [typeMismatch.timesheet.horaFim,typeMismatch.horaFim,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [
  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [timesheet.horaFim,horaFim]; 
  arguments []; 
  default message [horaFim]
]; 
default message [
  Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'horaFim'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Temporal @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date for value 'lala'; 
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
]
Field error in object 'timesheet' on field 'horaInicio': rejected value [teste]; 
codes [typeMismatch.timesheet.horaInicio,typeMismatch.horaInicio,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; 
arguments [
  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [timesheet.horaInicio,horaInicio]; 
  arguments []; 
  default message [horaInicio]
]; 
default message [
  Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'horaInicio'; 
  nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @javax.persistence.Temporal @javax.persistence.Column java.util.Date for value 'teste'; 
  nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
]
```

**How can I do it? Expect `Date` but I put `String` in the field, I'd like to validate before my controller.**

Comment: Your model class is expecting a `Date` value for the property `horaFim` but you are passing a invalid value like `lala` for the field from the client. Pass a correct value and try

Answer (score 10):

you need to add some binding to your Controller, something like :

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addtimesheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTimeSheet(@ModelAttribute("timesheet") TimeSheet timeSheet,
                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                           ModelMap model) {
  if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    // validation error (binding error) handling code goes here.
  }
}
```

Make sure bindingResult parameter is placed on the right after the timeSheet parameter.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.htm

```
Handler methods which are annotated with this annotation are allowed to 
have very flexible signatures. They may have arguments of the following types, 
in arbitrary order (except for validation results, which need to follow right 
after the corresponding command object, if desired)
```